# greasemonkey script try to access element before it exist and gets null

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, getelementbyid

I have small script running on "google.com/*" using Greasemonkey
basically my script adds a few menu items to google menu (where you can find Images Videos Maps News Shopping etc ...);

this menu is inside qbar div so its look like:

```
<div id="gbar"> ...menu code ... </div>
```

the next line in my script works fine if you go to google webpage (www.google.com):

```
var gbar = var gbar = document.getElementById("gbar");
if (qbar != null) alert("qbar exist!");
else alert("qbar is null");
```

this code alert qbar as exist which is good.

now if i look for anyword in google for example search for "madman" will get you to this page:

`http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=madman&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=fd0f73886609171d`

now the script still running only now it alert "gbar is null"

I think the reason is that the script is running before the gbar element get created on the page.  which is weird cuz i was sure the grease monkey script runs only when all content finished loading.

Comment: I assume there's a typo and qbar & gbar are the same object?

Answer (score 4):

You can set up a [DOM mutation event](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/DOM_events#Common.2FW3C_events). Basically, here are the steps:

- Do a initial search `document.getElementById('gbar')` and process it if found.
- Set up a [DOMNodeInserted](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php) event handler on the document.

  - If the inserted element has `id="gbar"` then you know that gbar is inserted.
  - If not, search inside the inserted element for an element with `id="gbar"` and process it if found.

You can see a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/thai/spYxc/) code. It adds 5 exclaimation marks when a `gbar` is added to the document.